# PyQGIS - get ellipsoid acronym of coordinate system of layer

Tags: pyqgis, ellipsoid

I  want to calculate the area of polygons in a layer with PyQGIS.

I am using the following code:

```
d= QgsDistanceArea()

for feature in layer.getFeatures():
        area = d.measureArea(feature.geometry())
        print("Area : {}".format(area))
```

The Problem is, the coordinate sytem I use is ETRS89 / UTM zone 32 N (EPSG:25832). Therefore the returned values are not correct. As far as I know, to get correct values I have to set the ellipsoid (GRS 1980) like this:

```
d.setEllipsoid('ACRONYM_OF_ELLIPSOID')
```

What is the best way to get the acronym of the used ellipsoid?
Is it possible to read the acronym of the ellipsoid from the coordinate system? And if yes, how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get the ellipsoid acronym from a CRS object (`QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem`).

For instance:

```
QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:25832").ellipsoidAcronym()
```

or, from a layer:

```
layer.sourceCrs().ellipsoidAcronym()
```

---

See the [docs](https://api.qgis.org/master/classQgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.html#a23384af6f9401c380effc74a1d5d8713) for details.